# Multipole expansion

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, harmonic-analysis

In *Simon's book Harmonic Analysis*, **example 3.5.12** shows:

Fix $x \in \mathbb{R}^{\nu}$ (with $\left.\nu \geq 3\right), x \neq 0$ and define $f$ on $\{y:| y|<| x |\}$ by
$$
f(y)=|x-y|^{-(\nu-2)}.
$$
Then we have$,$
$$
|x-y|^{-(\nu-2)}=\sum_{d=0}^{\infty} \frac{|y|^{d}}{|x|^{d+\nu-2}} \alpha_{\nu, d} Z_{d}\left(\frac{y}{|y|}, \frac{x}{|x|}\right) \label{1}\tag{$\ast$}
$$
where $\alpha_{\nu, d}$ is a constant which is dependent on $\nu, d$ and the $Z_{d}$ (the zonal harmonic of degree d) term at $y=0$ is interpreted as 1 if $d=0$ and is irrelevant if $d \geq 1$.

**My Question** is$,$ for fixed $x \in \mathbb{R}^{\nu}$ (with $\left.\nu \geq 3\right), x \neq 0$ and function $f(y)=|x-y|^{-\lambda}$ on $\{y|| y|<| x |\}$ with $\lambda>0,$ can we obtain a similar formula like \eqref{1} $?$

Any reference and suggestion will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Yes you just need Gegenbauer polynomials. See formula (2) of https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GegenbauerPolynomial.html